# edit an expression by rule to edit an URL in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey, edit

I wanna edit an href URL on es sprecific Site before I click on it.

Example URL in Quellcode:

```
href="http://de.example.com/product/02W30U190G0NAQCL35ZB3/go?context [...]
```

But the text after *product* has to be edited before
like 02**W**3**0**U**1**9**0**G**0**N**A**Q**C**L**3**5**Z**B**3**

1. cut out the 1st two characters and then every second.
   so the result should look like **W0100AC3Z3**
2. cut everything after */go?context* until to " (end of href)
3. and add an specific text */view.html"*

My biggest Problem is to edit the numbers and letters after product. The resultlenght (10) and the startlengt (21) is every time the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = 'http://de.example.com/product/02W30U190G0NAQCL35ZB3/go?context [...]';
var m = href.match(/^(.*?\/product\/)(\w{21})(\/go\?context)/);
var s21 = m && m[2];
if (s21) {
    var prefix = m[1];
    var suffix = m[3] + '/view.html';
    var s10 = '';
    for (var i = 2, c; c = s21[i]; i += 2) {
        s10 += c;
    }
    alert('Result = ' + prefix + s10 + suffix);
}
```